# Get system wide CPU usage on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cpu

I know it is possible to get the CPU usage of your own app (https://github.com/dani-gavrilov/GDPerformanceView) but is there a way (preferably in Swift) to get the current overall CPU usage of the phone?

[image]

Comment: @Moritz How does this app do it then? https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lirum-device-info-lite/id591660734?mt=8

Comment: @Moritz I added a picture in the question above showing a screenshot of the app

Comment: @Moritz Okay thanks. Does Apple officially allow low level code to be used though? I don't want my app to get banned.